# Connection reset by peer when when trying to access to Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose

I know it might be a repetitive question
but I already have tried them almost all with no success!

The problem is I can successfully communicate with 2 out of 3 images but all connection will be reset from **rotbeh.net.api**

I *exec* into the container and execute `curl localhost:5000` successfully but from outside nothing will happen

My API is written by C# net core 3.1 and
Here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  sqlserver:
    container_name: sqlserver
    image: mssql2019fts
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '/var/opt/mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data'
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA='Y'
      - SA_PASSWORD=******
      - FullText=true
    ports:
      - '1433:1433'

  rotbeh.net.api:
    container_name: rotbeh.net.api
    image: rotbeh.net.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on:
      - sqlserver

  rotbeh.net-ui:
    container_name: rotbeh.net-ui
    image: rotbeh.net-ui
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - rotbeh.net.api
```

Comment: How do you call it from "outside"?

Comment: Is your application listening on the container-private localhost interface?  (Do its startup messages say something like "listening on 127.0.0.1:5000"?)  Can you provide a [mcve], in particular with more description of how you're setting up the listener and how you're trying to call it?

Comment: @GuruStron the same as i call other containers curl localhost:5000

Comment: @DavidMaze yes in container logs I can see ```Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

Comment: @Kasra please see [this](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-54-fixing-connection-reset-by-peer-or-similar-errors) and [this](https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/)

Comment: @DavidMazeI have already set them like this:
 "Host": {
    "BaseUrl": "localhost",
    "Port": 5000
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "HttpsDefaultCert": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000",
        "Protocols": "Http1"
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to listen on '0.0.0.0' within the container. Your listener values should be something like:

```
{
   "Host":{
      "BaseUrl":"0.0.0.0",
      "Port":5000
   },
   "Kestrel":{
      "Endpoints":{
         "HttpsDefaultCert":{
            "Url":"0.0.0.0:5000",
            "Protocols":"Http1"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on! This is exactly what my problem was. Laravel container was listening on `127.0.0.1` within the container. Once I switched the host to `0.0.0.0` in the container, everything worked as expected! Thank you!